# Removing the index.php is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have this [site](http://dev.posnation.com/) and when you click on the go in the center i have it going to this url

```
 http://dev.posnation.com/welcome/redirect
```

which is not the proper page for the welcome controller and the redirect action. The proper url is

```
 http://dev.posnation.com/index.php/welcome/redirect
```

My codeigniter structure is like this

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 tamer  staff   225 Apr 11 13:09 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x@ 18 tamer  staff   612 Apr  8 17:26 application
drwxr-xr-x  11 tamer  staff   374 Apr 11 09:46 css
drwxr-xr-x@  6 tamer  staff   204 Mar 24 14:20 graphics
drwxr-xr-x  17 tamer  staff   578 Apr 11 09:54 js
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 tamer  staff   340 Apr  7 12:20 system
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 tamer  staff   544 Apr  7 12:20 user_guide
```

with the index.php out one directory

my .htaccess consists of this

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

You missed one Rewrite rule line after the RewriteCond. Try

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: still no .maybe its has something to do with where my index.php and my system and application folders live

Comment: Did you say your index.php is out one directory? Whats the name of the directory, or can you illustrate how you mean?

Comment: And have you removed index.php from your config files base_url?

Comment: Where is `index.php` located.  If it's up 1 directory, try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php/$1 [L]`.  If not, you may need to move the index.php into the same directory.

Comment: the name of the directory is posnation and yes it out one directory

Comment: where does the htaccess file go...in the same directory as the index.php

Comment: Hopefully this should do it. Put the .htaccess on the same level with index.php and the posnation folder, then add this line: RewriteBase /posnation/

Answer (score 1):

The [Codeigniter Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) supplies the following snipe:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Within your configuration please change the following variable accordingly:

```
config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING'; //set to QUERY_STRING
```

and

```
$config['index_page'] = ""; //Remove index.php
```

make sure your Apache mod_rewrite module is loaded (only if the above throws an 404).

there's plenty more issues it could be on http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

Comment: Will this produce site.com/index.php/controller/method though?

Comment: that didnt work...maybe its has something to do with where my index.php and my system and application folders live

Comment: this mainly redirects the uri to the index.php page, make sure your set to AUTO Within your Routes, and remove the `index.php` from your base_url in your config file, your system directory is server-side, this should have no effect.

Comment: its not working at all here is the correct page http://dev.posnation.com/index.php/welcome/redirect if you take out the index.php if fails

Comment: you do know that the htaccess file has to be within the same directory as index.php for it to take effect !!

Comment: fixed...it was other stuff in the htaccess that killed it

Comment: you never said anything about other content's within the file.

Comment: @RobertPitt Exactly. Tamer should have placed the entire htaccess file in his htaccess-related question rather than causing a wild-goose chase :)

Answer (score 0):

Its sometimes confusing as to what will work.  Try adding this as the last line

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. Make sure you get the RewriteRule right. Different methods also require different ways of catching the variables. I have seen two around, where one basically applies the $_GET array variable to the url variable as given in the example.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can catch 'm of respectively:

```
echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

echo $_GET['url'];
```

CodeIgniter uses index.php?/$1 . This caused problems with me.